# why is array len changed from 15 to 1 by using poly.fit_transform

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

np.random.seed(0)
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=1)
X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
model = LinearRegression().fit(X_poly, y_ploy)
```

and the ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 15]

I found that:
len(x) ->15,

```
array([  0.35281047,   0.79431716,   1.62431903,   2.59103578,
         3.23065446,   3.375973  ,   4.47573197,   4.96972856,
         5.69364194,   6.51069113,   7.17166586,   8.14799756,
         8.72363612,   9.31004929,  10.08877265])
```

while after poly.fit_transform,
len(X_poly)->1, and it inlude 16 numbers, seems 1. is added, but I dont know why it happens?

```
array([[  1.        ,   0.35281047,   0.79431716,   1.62431903,
          2.59103578,   3.23065446,   3.375973  ,   4.47573197,
          4.96972856,   5.69364194,   6.51069113,   7.17166586,
          8.14799756,   8.72363612,   9.31004929,  10.08877265]])
```

So the model cant be done, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand what you're trying to do because you haven't defined all of the variables that you are referring to.

However, when you are using numpy ndarrays, you shouldn't use `len` to find how big an array is. Instead of `len(x)` you should use `np.shape(x)` or `x.shape`. In this case, you will find that `np.shape(X_F1_poly)` is (1,16). If you look closely at the array you printed, you will find that there are double nested square brackets in the second one, as opposed to the single square brackets in the first one. This means that in `X_F1_poly` you basically have a list which has a single element (so length of 1) and that element is another 16 element list.

To get the list to be length 16, use `np.squeeze(X_F1_poly)` to remove that nesting.

Comment: I want to say why the poly.fit_transform() can change the structure of the original array, i am still confused, also thanks.